# Move title above image when they are in different columns in responsive view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've got an image and blog excerpt in two columns that display side by side in desktop view, but when in mobile view I'd like the blog title to be above the image. I'm not sure how to do this because they're in 2 columns, or is there an easier way to position the image?

```
    <div class="blogposts">
    <article class="one-post">
        <div class="blogposts-thumbs col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('',array('class' => 'img-fluid'));
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="blogposts-excerpts col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <h3><a href="page.html"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <ul class="date-info">
            <li class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
            <li><?php the_tags(); ?></li>
        </ul>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <span><a href="single-post.html">Continue reading <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: Put the title first, then the image -
 and use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering to get the desired column order in the desktop view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `.hidden-xs` and `.visible-xs` classes to show and hide in mobile

```
<div class="blogposts">
    <article class="one-post">
        <div class="blogposts-thumbs col-xs-12 col-sm-4">

            <h3 class="visible-xs"><a href="page.html"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('',array('class' => 'img-fluid'));
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="blogposts-excerpts col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

            <h3  class="hidden-xs"><a href="page.html"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <ul class="date-info">
            <li class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
            <li><?php the_tags(); ?></li>
        </ul>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <span><a href="single-post.html">Continue reading <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </article>
</div>
```